# How to send new direct message through Twitter API https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/events/new.json?

Tags: ruby, rest, api, twitter, ruby-on-rails-5

I am implementing Twitter new Direct message API,
[https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/events/new.json](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/direct-messages/sending-and-receiving/api-reference/new-event)

I am facing error,
415 Unsupported Media Type

I am able to call it via TWURL tool and currently I am sending simple text message through it.

From error code, I understand that either there is content-type issue or payload is in incorrect format.

I am passing payload as,

```
options = {
      "event": {
        "type": "message_create",
        "message_create": {
          "target": {
            "recipient_id": "1234"
          },
          "message_data": {
            "text": "test"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Payload is converted to usual Ruby hash, i.e. :key => "value"

```
{:event=>
  {:type=>"message_create",
   :message_create=>
    {:target=>{:recipient_id=>"1234"},
     :message_data=>{:text=>"test"}}}}
```

How to preserve third party API request format?

Any suggestion will be great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting `Content-Type ('application/json')`? in your content header before sending?

It is one of the most common issues.

You can do so by doing something similar to:

```
before_filter :set_content_type
  def set_content_type
    @headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  end
```

It will force your application to append the `Content-Type` on each request.

Comment: Yes header is added to set Content-Type, but still facing same error.

Comment: How do you send this? I'd `require 'json'` and then say for example `options={:event=>
  {:type=>"message_create",
   :message_create=>
    {:target=>{:recipient_id=>"1234"},
     :message_data=>{:text=>"test"}}}}`, and then send `options.to_json`. Also, according to documentation `Setting Content-Length may also be required if it is not automatically.`

Comment: I am implementing it through Twitter gem, and updating Headers in it is also raising another error.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/blob/master/TwitterAPIExchange.php

usa la clase  **TwitterAPIExchange** y aplica estos cambios.

Yo lo solucione modificando la clase así:

a la clase **TwitterAPIExchange** , añade la propiedad

```
public $appjson;
```

en **public function __construct(array $settings)** añade la inicialización.

```
$this->appjson=false;
```

en **public function performRequest($return = true, $curlOptions = array())**

remplaza

```
$header = array($this->buildAuthorizationHeader($this->oauth), 'Expect:');
```

por

```
if ($this->appjson) {
$header = array('Content-Type: application/json',$this->buildAuthorizationHeader($this->oauth), 'Expect:');
} else {
$header = array($this->buildAuthorizationHeader($this->oauth), 'Expect:');
}
```

para finalizar usa:

```
.....
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
......
......
$twitter->appjson=true;
$twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(true,
array( CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error and it turned out the data format I was sending the request in was a bit wrong. I was using python requests with the following headers:

```
HEADERS = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}
```

But still using `json.dumps()` on the actual data, the request was subsequently inconsistent with bad data, it all worked when I just sent the data without `dumps'ing` it.

This might not really help but just check your data integrity.